# Why does LilyPond describe sharps as "is" and flats as "es" by default?

Tags: music

In [LilyPond](http://www.lilypond.org/) the syntax to add a sharp to a note is **is** so that **fis** is f sharp, and the syntax to add a flat to a note is **es** so that **bes** is b flat.

I'm having trouble remembering this; is there a rationale behind this choice of syntax and can it be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because it's using the default setting of Dutch inflection notation:

> Alterations are made with different names: add -is for sharp, and -es for flat (these are Dutch note names, other languages are available). [LilyPond figures out where to put accidentals.](http://www.lilypond.org/text-input.html)

The -is and -es are for their relative phonological stresses.

If you want to use another suffix you can [change the language setting](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.17/Documentation/notation-big-page.html#note-names-in-other-languages). For example:

```
\language "english"
```

This way if you used English you would mark **-s** and **-f** for sharps and flats respectively.